# Ethers.js not connecting to Rinkeby when hardhat script run

Tags: ethers.js, rinkeby, hardhat

Can anyone help me understand how I can connect and interact with rinkeby? I'm using Alchemy to deploy my smart contract to rinkeby and I'm trying to run a script to check the network passed in the config, but I was a bit thrown off with  `homestead`  returned by the provider network despite my config file being configured with a rinkeby connection through Alchemy and setting --network rinkeby when the script is run. Am I missing something with the relationship between the config and running scripts? Do I need to pass rinkeby to the "name" parameter?

`hh run --network rinkeby scripts/rinkeby/get-rinkeby-info.js` // Returns "homestead" for console.log(provider.network);

**hardhat.config.js:**

```
networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: 'https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/x',
      accounts: ['id']
    }
  }
```

**get-rinkeby-info.js:**

```
const rinkebyInfo = async () => {
    const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    const provider = await hre.ethers.getDefaultProvider();
    console.log(provider.network);
};

const getRinkebyInfo = async () => {
    try {
        await rinkebyInfo();
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

getRinkebyInfo();
```

Comment: In your Alchemy Dashboard, is the app set to use Rinkeby network?

Comment: @pbsh yes it is. I discovered that the issue is the need to set the default provider information with the rinkeby, otherwise it was defaulting to the local network